# Como unir 3 consultas en sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Como puedo mostar en un solo select las siguientes 3 consultas?

```
select Top 1 NumOperador, Rendimiento, SdFecha
from trfRendimientos 
where (NumOperador = @NumOperador OR @NumOperador = 0)  
and (MONTH(SdFecha)= month(@FechaDesde)  and YEAR(SdFecha)=YEAR(@FechaDesde))

select 
RenUltimoMes=sum(Rendimiento)/count(Rendimiento)
from trfRendimientos 
where (NumOperador = @NumOperador OR @NumOperador = 0)  
and (MONTH(SdFecha)= month(@FechaDesde)-1  and YEAR(SdFecha)=YEAR(@FechaDesde))

select 
RentAnual=sum(Rendimiento)/count(Rendimiento)
from trfRendimientos 
where (NumOperador = @NumOperador OR @NumOperador = 0)  
and (month(SdFecha)>=month(1) and YEAR(SdFecha)=YEAR(@FechaDesde))
```

[image: Rendimiento]

Lo obtengo de la siguiente manera, yo quiero que me aparezca el RenUltimoMes a un lado de SdFecha y Ren Anual tambien en la primera consulta.

**Actualizado**

En la principal consulta es mostrar el ultimo Rendimiento ingresado en la tabla al día de hoy 20 Julio 2017 mostrando el numOperador y la SdFecha

En la Segunda es mostrar el Rendimiento por mes, pero debe ser a un mes anterior al ingresado en @FechaDesde.

En la Tercera es Mostrar el Rendimiento Anual de acuerdo al año ingresado en @FechaDesde.

Tomando en cuenta el @numoperador ya se un numOperador en especificio o mandando el numero 0 para que me regrese todos los que cumplen con las fechas ingresadas.

He colocado la primera Consulta que me ha indicado @Particio el Resultado es el siguiente:

[image: Consulta]

El Resultado es correcto con NumOperador, Rendimiento, SdFecha y Rendimiento Anual, el Rendimiento Ultimo Mes es el que me lo regresa en 0 y ahí hay registros por lo cual no debe de estar en 0.

Ajunto los Registros que tiene la tabla de trfRendimientos y que son los que deben de aparecer en el Rendimiento Ultimo de Mes.

Igual si yo mando en @numOperador=0 me regresa solo 1 registro que seria el ultimo y no me regresa los demas de la tabla, esto sería por el Top 1 que tengo en la primer consulta ahi tengo que cambiar es correcto?

**Modificado**

[image: Consulta]

Con esta nueva modificación ya me regresa los diferentes registros con el Ultimo Rendimeinto registrado y con el Rendimiento Anual, solo el rendimiento por mes es el que no me lo da, me da un 0, en la Imagen adjunta se puede ver que hay 2 registros del mes de Junio que son los que deberian de darme en el Rendimiento ultimo mes pero me da 0.

Comment: hay alguna llave foránea o campo que tengan ambas tablas?

Comment: Puedes usar una tabla temporal

Comment: @L.Ronquillo los Resultados son una misma tabla en este caso de trfRequerimientos, lo que cambia es el where para poder obtener el resultado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero que nada te cometo que hacer esto:

```
and (MONTH(SdFecha)= month(@FechaDesde)-1  and YEAR(SdFecha)=YEAR(@FechaDesde))
```

para filtrar registros de un mes anterior al período solicitado no va a funcionar, imagina que `@FechaDesde` es `12/1/2017` entonces `month(@FechaDesde)-1 = 0` y obviamente no existe el mes `0`, además deberías ajustar en ese caso el año, por que lo que en definitiva quieres es ver lo del 12/2016. Una forma de resolverlo es la siguiente:

```
MONTH(SdFecha) = MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, @FechaDesde) and YEAR(SdFecha) = YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, @FechaDesde))
```

Es decir, traslado la fecha un mes para atrás y ahora sí miro mes y año.

Por supuesto la solución de Ariel de usar variables es válida, pero para ofrecerte una alternativa, vamos a usar subconsultas y joins así:

```
select  
    R1.NumOperador, 
    R1.SdFecha,
    R1.Rendimiento            as 'RenMesActual', 
    ISNULL(R2.RenUltimoMes,0) as 'RenUltimoMes',
    ISNULL(R3.RentAnual,0)    as 'RentAnual'
    from trfRendimientos R1
    -- máximo rendimiento del período solicitado por operador
    INNER JOIN ( select NumOperador, MAX(SdFecha) AS 'MaxSdFechaMes'
        from trfRendimientos 
        where CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR,SdFecha, 111)) BETWEEN @FechaDesde AND @FechaHasta)
        group by NumOperador
    ) A
       ON A.NumOperador = R1.NumOperador
       AND A.MaxSdFechaMes = R1.SdFecha
    -- mes anterior
    left join (select NumOperador,
            sum(Rendimiento)/count(Rendimiento) as RenUltimoMes
            from trfRendimientos 
            where   MONTH(SdFecha) = MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, @FechaDesde) and YEAR(SdFecha) = YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, @FechaDesde))  
            group by NumOperador
        ) R2
        ON R2.NumOperador = R1.NumOperador
    -- año actual
    left join (select NumOperador,
            sum(Rendimiento)/count(Rendimiento) as RentAnual
            from trfRendimientos 
            where   (month(SdFecha)>=month(1) and YEAR(SdFecha)=YEAR(@FechaDesde))
            group by NumOperador
        ) R3
        ON R3.NumOperador = R1.NumOperador
    where   (R1.NumOperador = @NumOperador OR @NumOperador = 0)
```

Ten en cuenta, que no tengo definido ni el modelo ni algún ejemplo, así que puede haber algún error en la consulta, pero espero entiendas la idea. Eventualmente podría ser posible resolver todo con un único `SELECT` pero creo que quedaría bastante más complejo de entender.

#### EDITADO

Después del último comentario de Molita rehago la consulta modificando el `WHERE` por `and CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR,R1.SdFecha, 111)) = @FechaDesde`, lo que se busca es que la consulta principal devuelva los valores del día consultado sin importar la hora.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @Patricio, lo que me indicas en mi Select Principal de mostrar el NumOperador, Rendimiento y SdFecha, es mostrar el Rendimiento actual del día (Mostar el Ren. del día 20 de Julio 2017) en mi pregunta coloco más ya que aquí solo me permite unas cuantas palabras espero a verme explicado.

Comment: Ahí edite la respuesta para que quede más cercana a tu pregunta. Saludos

Comment: he quitado el Top 1 y modificado el where como me lo indicas pero ahora no me regresa ningun Resultado.

Comment: Por lo único que podría no traerte registros es por que no los hay con la `@FechaDesde` solicitada o que esta variable tenga también la hora

Comment: pues tengo los datos de la siguiente manera: Declare NumOperador int, FechaDesde datetime, FechaHasta datetime
set FechaDesde='2017-07-03 00:00:00.000'
set FechaHasta='2017-07-12 00:00:00.000'
set NumOperador=452127 y en la tabla de trfRequerimientos si hay de mes de Junio y julio. Retire los @ ya que no me permitia ingresarlos

Comment: Esto `select * from trfRendimientos R1 where (R1.NumOperador =   NumOperador OR @NumOperador = 0)  and CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR,R1.SdFecha, 111)) = @FechaDesde`  te devuelve registros?

Comment: no, no me regresa Registros

Comment: Con eso confirmamos que el problema lo tienes en algún filtro, básicamente no hay registros para `NumOperador` y/o `SdFecha`, recuerda que por lo que has comentado quieres encontrar una fecha en particular por eso hacemos `CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR,R1.SdFecha, 111)) = @FechaDesde`, pero en la consulta inicial estabas pidiendo todas las fechas del mes actual.

Comment: Entonces creo que no me explique bien :S  al momento de colocar la FechaDesde = 2017-07-03 y FechaHasta = 2017-07-20, yo quiero buscar que me regrese en Redimiento, el ultimo rendimiento ingresado al día actual, por Ejemplo que si el ultimo Rendimiento registrado es el día 18 de Julio me regrese ese rendimiento o si es el 20 de Julio me regrese el del 20 de Julio, ya con el Rendimiento por mes si sería un mes anterior sería mes de Junio y el Rendimeinto Anual sería por el año que esta ingresado en FechaDesde que sería 2017

Comment: Bien.. entonces lo que debes hacer antes que nada es obtener cual es la `SdFecha` máxima dentro del período que solicitas y por cada `NumOperador`, con esa consulta haces un `INNER` y entiendo deberías llegar a lo solicitado. Revisa mi última edición. Saludos

Comment: Gracias Patricio con esto ya puedo ver los registros en la pregunta adjunto una imagen de como ya se pueden ver con el ultimo rendimiento, solo el calulco del rendimiento del mes es el que no me lo da me lo da en 0

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62552/discussion-between-patricio-moracho-and-molitaa).

Answer (score 2):

Podes setear las variables antes y luego agregarlas a la consulta

```
declare @RenUltimoMes REAL,@RentAnual REAL



select 
@RenUltimoMes=sum(Rendimiento)/count(Rendimiento)
from trfRendimientos 
where (NumOperador = @NumOperador OR @NumOperador = 0)  
and (MONTH(SdFecha)= month(@FechaDesde)-1  and YEAR(SdFecha)=YEAR(@FechaDesde))

select 
@RentAnual=sum(Rendimiento)/count(Rendimiento)
from trfRendimientos 
where (NumOperador = @NumOperador OR @NumOperador = 0)  
and (month(SdFecha)>=month(1) and YEAR(SdFecha)=YEAR(@FechaDesde))


select Top 1 NumOperador, Rendimiento, SdFecha,@RenUltimoMes as RenUltimoMes,@RentAnual as  RenAnual
from trfRendimientos 
where (NumOperador = @NumOperador OR @NumOperador = 0)  
and (MONTH(SdFecha)= month(@FechaDesde)  and YEAR(SdFecha)=YEAR(@FechaDesde))
```

Answer (score 0):

No se si funciona en SQLServer, pero en Mysql lo he testeado y puedes hacer un select dentro de otro, asi:

```
select resultado1, (select resultado 2
                    from tabla 2
                    where...), (select resultado 3
                                from tabla 3
                                where .....)
from tabla
where....;
```

he intentado hacerlo con tu codigo, pero se veia mal.... espero que hayas podido ver la idea